# how do i connect my raspberry pi to WIFI without ethernel cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

how do i connect my raspberry pi to WIFI without ethernet cable. I have a wifi dongle or usb connected to my pi but the internet still doesnt work unless i connect a ethernet canble. can someone please help me out

Comment: Have you setup your SD card?

Comment: what do you mean? I have raspian installed on my sd card

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your wi-fi via the command line, see a detailed guide on the official site:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Another option is to use the PIXEL desktop:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/pixel-desktop.md

Comment: it recognizes and connects to the wifi but as soon as I disconnect the ethernet cable it, theres no internet

Comment: seems to be a problem with your connection or a faulty wifi dongle, does the dongle work on other devices? (pc?)